# Can the source code from Lua or Ruby be used within a BASH script?

Tags: ruby, bash, lua

If I have a BASH script, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp file1.txt file2.txt
```

Can I add source code from other languages, such as Lua or Ruby inside the BASH script, stored in the same file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could embed the source in a "here document" (search the manpage for that string), and at runtime of the bash script, create the scripts in /tmp or wherever you wish to execute them; alternatively, you could pipe the "here document" to the scripting engines if they accept input from stdin.

I don't know enough Ruby or Lua, but here's some Python via Bash:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat <<EOF | python -
print "this is a test"
print "so is this"
import sys, os
print sys.path, os.getcwd()
EOF
```